# How to create python dictionary from cassandra tables values?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, cassandra

I'm trying to create one application, in which I want to load one Cassandra table in python dictionary.

**Table looks like below -**

```
 startup_id | startup_name
-----------+---------------------
         1 |     name
         2 |     gender
         3 |     address
         4 |     pincode     
         5 |     phoneno
```

I want to load this table in python dictionary.

**Expected Output-**

```
{'name': '1' , 'gender': '2', 'address': '3', 'pincode': '4', 'phoneno': '5'}
```

**NOTE -** startup_name column is unique so we can add this as a key in python dictionary.

Currently I'm following below way to do that -

```
main_dict = {}
rows = session.execute('SELECT startup_id,startup_name FROM startup;')
for (id, name) in rows:
    main_dict[name] = id
```

I want to know, Is their any simple and faster way to do this? Any answers which will make performance faster will be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4):

Here is a link to the Cassandra documentation that has a code example of returning rows as dicts: https://datastax.github.io/python-driver/api/cassandra/query.html#cassandra.query.dict_factory
Basically, you change the row factory for the session to dict_factory.

```
session = cluster.connect(...)
session.row_factory = dict_factory
session.execute(...)
```

By the way, by default, the returned rows are already named tuples so you can use column names as object members, like this:

```
rows = session.execute("select peer,release_version,rack,data_center from system.peers;")
  for row in rows:
    print(row.release_version, row.rack, row.data_center)
```

Comment: "session.row_factory = dict_factory" does not work for frozen UDTs